# Pandas sort column values with "0" values at end of column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 2, 0, 0, -3, -2, 1]}).sort_values('A')
Out[6]: 
   A
4 -3
5 -2
2  0
3  0
6  1
1  2
0  5
```

I would like to have "0" values at the end when sorting so my resulting dataframe looks like this.

```
   A
4 -3
5 -2
6  1
1  2
0  5
2  0
3  0
```

Is there a simple (1 line of code) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `mask` the zeros then use [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on column `A` to get the indices that would sort the dataframe:

```
df.iloc[df['A'].replace(0, np.nan).to_numpy().argsort()]
```

---

```
   A
4 -3
5 -2
6  1
1  2
0  5
2  0
3  0
```

Comment: Thanks. can I also use in descending order?

Comment: @idt_tt yes you can simply multiply by `-1` i.e  `df.iloc[df['A'].mul(-1).replace(0, np.nan).to_numpy().argsort()]
`

Answer (score 2):

Let's try adding a new column and sort by two columns:

```
df.assign(dummy=df.A.eq(0)).sort_values(['dummy','A']).drop('dummy', axis=1)
```

Another option, not quite a one-liner, is `mask` and `concat`:

```
mask = df['A'].eq(0)
df = pd.concat([df[~mask].sort_values('A'), df[mask]])
```

Output:

```
   A
4 -3
5 -2
6  1
1  2
0  5
2  0
3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `key` in `sort_values()`

`df.sort_values(by='A', key=lambda col: col.replace(0, np.nan), na_position='last')`